# How to insert or update (if exists) to table with inner special select

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update or insert to table range of dates with some data.
For example, I get startDate = 01/01/2022 and endDate = 01/01/2023, and I need to add 365 rows on this table or update the relevant rows in the table.

I tried to do this, but it's not working:

```sql
MERGE INTO TABLE_DATE 
USING ( 
SELECT DT + (LEVEL - 1) DD, 20180 aaa ,10000 bbb
FROM (SELECT DATE '2017-03-05' DT FROM DUAL)
CONNECT BY DT + (LEVEL-1) <= DATE '2017-04-11'
) B
ON (B.DD = TABLE_DATE.DATE AND B.aa = TABLE_DATE.aaa AND B.bbb = 
TABLE_DATE.bbb )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET TABLE_DATE.ccc = 100
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (ID, DATE, aaa, bbb, ccc) VALUES (1, B.DD,B.aaa,B.bbb, 100);
```

Comment: Please specify what you mean with _"it's not working"_.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you said what "not working" means ...

Because, it works for me.

Table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE table_date
  2  (
  3     id      NUMBER,
  4     datum   DATE,
  5     aaa     NUMBER,
  6     bbb     NUMBER,
  7     ccc     NUMBER
  8  );

Table created.
```

One sample row (which will be updated by `MERGE`):

```
SQL> INSERT INTO table_date (id,
  2                          datum,
  3                          aaa,
  4                          bbb,
  5                          ccc)
  6       VALUES (1,
  7               DATE '2017-03-05',
  8               20180,
  9               10000,
 10               NULL);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Merge:

```
SQL> MERGE INTO TABLE_DATE
  2       USING (    SELECT DT + (LEVEL - 1) DD,
  3                         20180 aaa,
  4                         10000 bbb,
  5                         LEVEL new_id
  6                    FROM (SELECT DATE '2017-03-05' DT FROM DUAL)
  7              CONNECT BY DT + (LEVEL - 1) <= DATE '2017-04-11') B
  8          ON (    B.DD = TABLE_DATE.datum
  9              AND B.aaa = TABLE_DATE.aaa
 10              AND B.bbb = TABLE_DATE.bbb)
 11  WHEN MATCHED
 12  THEN
 13     UPDATE SET TABLE_DATE.ccc = 999
 14  WHEN NOT MATCHED
 15  THEN
 16     INSERT     (ID,
 17                 datum,
 18                 aaa,
 19                 bbb,
 20                 ccc)
 21         VALUES (b.new_id,
 22                 B.DD,
 23                 B.aaa,
 24                 B.bbb,
 25                 100);

38 rows merged.
```

Result:

```
SQL>   SELECT *
  2      FROM table_date
  3  ORDER BY datum;

        ID DATUM             AAA        BBB        CCC
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 05.03.2017      20180      10000        999   --> this was updated
         2 06.03.2017      20180      10000        100   --> all subsequent rows were inserted
         3 07.03.2017      20180      10000        100
         4 08.03.2017      20180      10000        100
         5 09.03.2017      20180      10000        100
        <snip>
        29 02.04.2017      20180      10000        100
        30 03.04.2017      20180      10000        100
        31 04.04.2017      20180      10000        100
        32 05.04.2017      20180      10000        100
        33 06.04.2017      20180      10000        100
        34 07.04.2017      20180      10000        100
        35 08.04.2017      20180      10000        100
        36 09.04.2017      20180      10000        100
        37 10.04.2017      20180      10000        100
        38 11.04.2017      20180      10000        100

38 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: I got this : SQL Error: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Comment: ok, my column name is date which is not correct to use in oracle... , any idea how can I get id's based on row number? (I can't put 1 for all ids)

Comment: You already have LEVEL pseudocolumn - use it for the ID value. I edited the answer, have a look.

Comment: thank you! another question... I'm trying to do it in sql also, so I change the select statment:
MERGE INTO TABLE_DATE
USING 
WITH ListDates(AllDates) AS
(SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,'2017-03-05') AS DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,AllDates)
    FROM ListDates 
    WHERE AllDates < DATEADD(DAY,-1,'2017-04-11'))
    SELECT AllDates
    FROM ListDates) as b
ON (B.DD = TABLE_DATE.DATE )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TABLE_DATE.ccc = 100
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (ID, DATE, aaa, bbb, ccc) VALUES (1, B.DD, 123, 456 , 100);

Comment: This is a) difficult to read, b) what is "another question"?